# Ввод чисел в разные переменные в цикле

Tags: c#

Всем привет. 
Нашел пример, использования цикла for, для получения введенных данных:

```
int[] nums = new int[7];
Console.WriteLine("Введите семь чисел");
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("{0}-е число: ", i + 1);
    nums[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

У меня возник вопрос: как можно используя данный способ, записать все 7 введенных чисел в семь переменных? То есть, каждому числу, своя переменная.

Спасибо.

Comment: Так обычно стараются не делать, а используют массивы - потому что это удобнее, чем оперировать с разными переменными. Код унифицированнее, короче и проще в отладке.  Если у вас это школьная задача то вы ещё тем более не должны знать про всякие сложные темы типа рефлексии.

Comment: Это не школьная)). Я сам по себе учу C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Но это мастурбация в чистом виде.  Учитесь так не делать.

```
int[] nums = new int[7];
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0, num5 = 0, num6 = 0, num7 = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Введите семь чисел");
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
  Console.Write("{0}-е число: ", i + 1);
  switch(i) {
    case 0:
      num1 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
      break;
    case 1:
      num2 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
      break;
    case 2:
      num3 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
      break;
    case 3:
      num4 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
      break;
    case 4:
      num5 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
      break;
    case 5:
      num6 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
      break;
    case 6:
      num7 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
      break;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Согласен))). Это извращение)). Вообщем для себя я понял.